# Pandas DataFrame.to_csv last column missing when field is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am extracting data from a database into a csv file.

I realize that each time the last field of a row in Null, then DataFrame.to_csv omit it.
This only happens when the empty field is at the last position.

Here is an exemple :

```
dframe_iterator = pandas.read_sql_query(request, engine, chunksize=1000)
for i, dataframe in enumerate(dframe_iterator):   
        dataframe.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=True, sep='|', mode='a', encoding='utf-8', date_format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Let say one n-uplet returned by the sql query contains 2 Null values :

```
'blabla','blabla',Null, 'blabla', Null
```

Then, in the csv file, i get :

```
blabla|blabla||blabla
```

You can see that the first Null field is there (||) but the second Null filed is omitted.

I would expect this :

```
blabla|blabla||blabla|
```

Do you have any idea how to perform this?
Another application is expecting as much fields as returned by  the sql query.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give a minimum example dataframe? I'm struggling to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Sorry Draco. It's normal that you cannot reproduce this. My question was wrong. The pandas behaviour is perfect and exactly how i expected it. Too fast to post, not testing enough, and stupid me!

Comment: Please consider deleting the question.. Since nothing is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Hemm, well, I apologie but my question was wrong.

Actually, the pandas behaviour is perfectly good :

```
'blabla','blabla',Null, 'blabla', Null
```

would be :

```
blabla|blabla||blabla|
```

I have been troubled by a dataset having lots of Null field at last positions.
Working on a different dataset made me realize this.
And also wrong client specs which would expect `blabla|blabla||blabla||`

I really do apologie for being stupid and too fast to post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried parameter `na_rep`? [Doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
  na_rep : string, default ‘’
       Missing data representation
```